# Azure Logic App get all Jira ticket instead of one

Tags: azure, get, key, jira, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to get group of ticket on Azure Logic App instead of getting only one by Key?

I need to get all ticket created over a month and then use a loop to check which one is contain the needed data to add comment on it.

Comment: Have you looked at using the REST API’s?

Comment: If you retrieve all tickets in an object array you can try to use the "Filter array" action to filter out the ticket with a property that matches your need,

Comment: @Skin I am not sure if I am allowed to use it since the requirements says to use Azure Logic App.

Comment: @KjMo the problem is that I don't have idea on how to retrieve all the tickets

Comment: No no, you call the relevant REST API’s from within LogicApps. It sounds like you have a bit to learn/read up on.

Comment: @Skin oh ok thank you I will do some more research on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Skin for pointing out in the right direction. Fetching data through REST API worked for me. Below is the flow of my Logic app.

[image]

*GET*

```
https://<YOUR_DOMAIN>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=<PROJECTID>&fields=issue,status,name&startAt=0&maxResults=8000
```

***RESULTS***

[image]

Comment: How about if I want to specify the date instead of startAt=0&maxResults=8000. Also if I want the issue type to be standard not a sub-task. I tried to follow the same url you provide but I feel that there is something wrong. (........&fields=issue,summary,issuetype&created>=-15d&hierarchylevel=0 )