# Logic App using HTTP Action to access and GET Jira ticket

Tags: http, url, field, jira, azure-logic-apps

So I followed this answer and it works fine:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74981947/20829088

Provided URL:

```
https://<YOUR_DOMAIN>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=<PROJECTID>&fields=issue,status,name&startAt=0&maxResults=8000
```

However, it take a lot of time. So, if I want the url to check for specific ticket depending on created time and type of ticket. For example
I want ticket that is **created within 15 days** and that are **NOT a sub-task.**

so I tried something like this.

```
.....&fields=issue,summary,issuetype&created>=-15d&hierarchylevel=0
```

I'm not sure of how it should be written I just tried this and it doesn't work.

Here is the request result in JSON:

***It should be earthier [subtask=false] OR [hierarchylevel=0] OR [name=Task]***

[image]

Comment: Have you tried &filter=hierarchylevel eq '0'

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve this using `Condition` connector of logic apps. I have initialized an array variable first and then tried to append each item that satisfies the condition. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

and then I used Parse Json to retrieve the required values for condition comparision

[image]

[image]

You can use the below Code view to reproduce the same in your environment.

```
{"definition":{"$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#","actions":{"For_each":{"actions":{"Compose":{"inputs":"@items('For_each')?['fields']?['created']","runAfter":{},"type":"Compose"},"Condition":{"actions":{"Append_to_array_variable":{"inputs":{"name":"Array","value":"@items('For_each')"},"runAfter":{},"type":"AppendToArrayVariable"}},"expression":{"or":[{"greaterOrEquals":["@formatDateTime(outputs('Compose'),'yyyy-MM-dd')","@formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-15),'yyyy-MM-dd')"]},{"equals":["@items('For_each')?['fields']?['issuetype']?['subtask']",false]},{"equals":["@items('For_each')?['fields']?['issuetype']?['hierarchyLevel']",0]},{"equals":["@items('For_each')?['fields']?['status']?['statusCategory']?['name']","Task"]}]},"runAfter":{"Compose":["Succeeded"]},"type":"If"}},"foreach":"@body('Parse_JSON')?['issues']","runAfter":{"Parse_JSON":["Succeeded"]},"type":"Foreach"},"HTTP":{"inputs":{"authentication":{"password":"<API_KEY>","type":"Basic","username":"<USERNAME>"},"method":"GET","uri":"https://jira@<ProjectName>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=<ProjectID>"},"runAfter":{},"type":"Http"},"Initialize_variable":{"inputs":{"variables":[{"name":"Array","type":"array"}]},"runAfter":{"HTTP":["Succeeded"]},"type":"InitializeVariable"},"Parse_JSON":{"inputs":{"content":"@body('HTTP')","schema":{"properties":{"expand":{"type":"string"},"issues":{"items":{"properties":{"expand":{"type":"string"},"fields":{"properties":{"aggregateprogress":{"properties":{"progress":{"type":"integer"},"total":{"type":"integer"}},"type":"object"},"aggregatetimeestimate":{},"aggregatetimeoriginalestimate":{},"aggregatetimespent":{},"assignee":{},"components":{"type":"array"},"created":{"type":"string"},"creator":{"properties":{"accountId":{"type":"string"},"accountType":{"type":"string"},"active":{"type":"boolean"},"avatarUrls":{"properties":{"16x16":{"type":"string"},"24x24":{"type":"string"},"32x32":{"type":"string"},"48x48":{"type":"string"}},"type":"object"},"displayName":{"type":"string"},"emailAddress":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string"},"timeZone":{"type":"string"}},"type":"object"},"customfield_10001":{},"customfield_10002":{},"customfield_10003":{},"customfield_10004":{},"customfield_10005":{},"customfield_10006":{},"customfield_10007":{},"customfield_10008":{},"customfield_10009":{},"customfield_10010":{},"customfield_10014":{},"customfield_10015":{},"customfield_10016":{},"customfield_10017":{"type":"string"},"customfield_10018":{"properties":{"hasEpicLinkFieldDependency":{"type":"boolean"},"nonEditableReason":{"properties":{"message":{"type":"string"},"reason":{"type":"string"}},"type":"object"},"showField":{"type":"boolean"}},"type":"object"},"customfield_10019":{"type":"string"},"customfield_10020":{},"customfield_10021":{},"customfield_10022":{},"customfield_10023":{},"customfield_10024":{},"customfield_10025":{},"customfield_10026":{},"customfield_10027":{},"customfield_10028":{},"customfield_10029":{},"customfield_10030":{},"customfield_10033":{},"description":{},"duedate":{},"environment":{},"fixVersions":{"type":"array"},"issuelinks":{"type":"array"},"issuetype":{"properties":{"avatarId":{"type":"integer"},"description":{"type":"string"},"entityId":{"type":"string"},"hierarchyLevel":{"type":"integer"},"iconUrl":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string"},"subtask":{"type":"boolean"}},"type":"object"},"labels":{"type":"array"},"lastViewed":{},"priority":{"properties":{"iconUrl":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string"}},"type":"object"},"progress":{"properties":{"progress":{"type":"integer"},"total":{"type":"integer"}},"type":"object"},"project":{"properties":{"avatarUrls":{"properties":{"16x16":{"type":"string"},"24x24":{"type":"string"},"32x32":{"type":"string"},"48x48":{"type":"string"}},"type":"object"},"id":{"type":"string"},"key":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"projectTypeKey":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string"},"simplified":{"type":"boolean"}},"type":"object"},"reporter":{"properties":{"accountId":{"type":"string"},"accountType":{"type":"string"},"active":{"type":"boolean"},"avatarUrls":{"properties":{"16x16":{"type":"string"},"24x24":{"type":"string"},"32x32":{"type":"string"},"48x48":{"type":"string"}},"type":"object"},"displayName":{"type":"string"},"emailAddress":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string"},"timeZone":{"type":"string"}},"type":"object"},"resolution":{},"resolutiondate":{},"security":{},"status":{"properties":{"description":{"type":"string"},"iconUrl":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string"},"statusCategory":{"properties":{"colorName":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"integer"},"key":{"type":"string"},"name":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string"}},"type":"object"}},"type":"object"},"statuscategorychangedate":{"type":"string"},"subtasks":{"type":"array"},"summary":{"type":"string"},"timeestimate":{},"timeoriginalestimate":{},"timespent":{},"updated":{"type":"string"},"versions":{"type":"array"},"votes":{"properties":{"hasVoted":{"type":"boolean"},"self":{"type":"string"},"votes":{"type":"integer"}},"type":"object"},"watches":{"properties":{"isWatching":{"type":"boolean"},"self":{"type":"string"},"watchCount":{"type":"integer"}},"type":"object"},"workratio":{"type":"integer"}},"type":"object"},"id":{"type":"string"},"key":{"type":"string"},"self":{"type":"string"}},"required":["expand","id","self","key","fields"],"type":"object"},"type":"array"},"maxResults":{"type":"integer"},"startAt":{"type":"integer"},"total":{"type":"integer"}},"type":"object"}},"runAfter":{"Initialize_variable":["Succeeded"]},"type":"ParseJson"}},"contentVersion":"1.0.0.0","outputs":{},"parameters":{},"triggers":{"manual":{"inputs":{"schema":{}},"kind":"Http","type":"Request"}}},"parameters":{}}
```